# How do I get those type of borders around the white boxes using xml in android dev?

Tags: android

[image]

I am learning android dev. I wanted to know how to get these type of borders.
I tried using layer-list but it doesnt give me that blurry effect. Also, tried with elevation but for some reason it doesnt give me any effect on my phone but it gets previewed in android studio correctly.

Comment: you can use cardview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**compile this library**

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

than add cardview to your layout like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
  // add all your controls here
 </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

for more information [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)  or [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/)
or  [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)

Comment: I am getting namespace 'app' not bound.

Answer (score 0):

That is a `CardView`. It is available in android support library. You need to add the dependency first in the module gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // change to your desired version
}
```

It has interesting properties like

```
cardBackgroundColor
cardCornerRadius
cardElevation
```

Check [a link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for more info.